# How does using a relational operator in an algebraic expression work?

Tags: c, operator-precedence, post-increment, relational-operators

I came across a piece of code where `<=` is used in an algebraic expression in C.

```
int x=2, y=4, z=5, m=10;
m+= x * y + z++ <=m+3;
printf("%d, %d", m,z);
```

I've never seen the use of a relational operator in this manner and wondered how the output of this is being computed. The output that I receive when running this is 11, 6. In what way does `<=` work here?

Comment: This code is horrible. I strongly recommend you don't replicate it. It returns 1 if the inequality is true, zero otherwise.

Comment: Yes, the relational operator <= evaluates to 0 (false) or 1 (true), so the value of x * y + z++ <= m + 3 is 1. So m is incremented by 1 (as is z via the unary ++). Yes, it's ugly and pointless code, but it's helpful to learn how things work.

Comment: Here the precedence of operators is important. Adding parenthesis it becomes more readable `m += ( ((x * y) + z++) <= (m+3) )`. We add to `m` the result of a test which is 1 for `true` and 0 for `false`.

Comment: "I came across a piece of code". I see. May I assume that you came across it in a homework exercise or an exam question? Because I strongly believe that code like this (ugly, non-selfexplanatory, no sensible context) cannot occur anywhere else.

Comment: @Yunnosch Indeed.  And the correct answer to the exam/homework question is, "I don't care what the code will print out and I'm not wasting time trying to figure it out.  The code failed code review and will be rewritten into something understandable and maintainable."

Answer (score 5):

This statement

```
m+= x * y + z++ <=m+3;
```

may be rewritten like

```
m += (x * y + z++ ) <= ( m+3 );
```

due to precedence of operators.

Taking into account these declarations

```
int x=2, y=4, z=5, m=10;
```

the operand `(x * y + z++ )`  of the relational operator `<=` is equal to `2 * 4 + 5` that is equal to `13` (pay attention to that the value of the postfix increment operator is the value of its operand before incrementing) , `m + 3`  is also equal to `13`. So the relational operator yields `1`.

And in fact you have

```
m += 1;
```

From the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 6 **Each of the operators** < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less
> than or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) **shall yield 1
> if the specified relation is true** and 0 if it is false.107) The
> result has type int.

As a result `m` will be equal to `11` and `z` due to the postfix increment operator after this statement will be equal to `6`.

Answer (score 3):

The result of a relational expression is 0 (if the expression is false) or 1 (if the expression is true).

So

```
m += x * y + z++ <= m + 3;
```

will add 1 to `m` if the result of `x * y + z++` is less than or equal to the result of `m + 3`, 0 otherwise.

Based on the initial values of `x`, `y`, `z`, and `m`, the relational expression should evaluate to true.

Never, ever write code like this.  This is *bad*.  Yes, I'm guilty of using relational and logical expressions in a similar manner in assignments, but not with so many side effects.